# Creating dropdown and populating unique value in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am very new to Vue js. We are displaying a table on UI having 4 columns as 
S.No | Column | Description | Type

We need to list all the unique value in Type in a drop-down (describing the datatype of a column), I am able to make Type as a drop-down however struggling to get the list of unique values in Type.

I am getting all data in an Array [sno:(..), column:(..), description:(..), type:(..)] and I am trying to get to type to put the value in one of the array and the taking unique value from that.
The code I tried first is

```
this.columnType = this.columnData.filter(data => {return data.type.toUpperCase()});
```

Also, I tried the following but it is just filtering on the specific datatype in this case "Timestamp"

```
this.columnType = this.columnData.filter(function(data) {
  return data.type.toUpperCase() == "TIMESTAMP_NTZ"
});
```

Looking for some guidance to get this right.

Thanks in advance to all for helping

Answer (score 0):

Use the following computed property to get the list of unique Type values:

```js
computed:
{
  onlyTypes()
  {
    // we want an Array with all the Type values
    return this.tableDataRows.map(dataItem => dataItem.type);
  },
  uniqueTypes()
  {
    // we want only the unique Type values
    return this.onlyTypes.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
  }
}
```